# PHP Session and it's variables

Tags: php, session, variables, unset

When user come to site by link with activation code, his account activated (changed value in DB) and I want show some info message. For this I reload page with `$_SESSION['message'] = "activated"` (same time removing activation code from URL). Info message block code:

```
<? if ($_SESSION['message'] === "activated") { 
ShowAlert('ActivatedOk-popup');

echo '
<div id="ActivatedOk-popup" class="info-popup">
<div class="popup-info-wrapper"><div class="leaflet-popup-close-button">×</div>
    <div class="popup-header">'.ACTIVATION_POP_HEADER.'</div>
    <div class="popupRecord1">
               <p>'.ACTIVATION_POP_TEXT1.$_SESSION['name'].ACTIVATION_POP_TEXT2.'</p>
    </div>
    <button class="popup-btn close_but">'.ACTIVATION_POP_BTN.'</button>
</div>
</div>';

unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
?>
```

But I can't understand why this pop-up doesn't appears. If I remove last line: `$_SESSION['message'] = "";` everything work well, but Message variable isn't empty, and each page appears pop-up. How correctly show pop-up and then unset variable?

Comment: Have you used `session_start()`?

Comment: +1 for Phil's comment, and you probably don't need the identical comparison (`===`) just equals (`==`)

Comment: Refrain from using == instead of ===.

Comment: Of course, session started, without UNSET, it works well. There is no matter, if I use comparison or equals sign. I can't understand why variable unset before generate pop-up message.

Comment: echo your (to check) the value of `$_SESSION['message']` without unset, does it gives _"activated"_ .

Answer (score 0):

you got to start/initialize a session *session_start();*  before trying to use any session variable. 
check by echoing your $_SESSION['message'] once after initializing

---

`<? 
       session_start();
      //echo $_SESSION['message'];

    ?>`

Comment: Session is work. If I remove last line (unset), I can see in session file on server variable "message". But with last line, this variable removed.

Comment: echo your (to check) the value of `$_SESSION['message']` without unset, does it gives _"activated"_ .

Answer (score 0):

Your code is theoretically correct. Like the comment of anonymous states you should use `session_start();` to make sure the session is active. (See PHP ini setting session "autostart" - the setting may vary on different servers).

Regarding your code: I would recommend not to use short open tags (because these may be not allowed on different configurations).. and I would recommend checking if the session varialble exists before checking for its contents, to avoid uneccessary notices, e.g.:

```
<? if (isset($_SESSION['message']) && $_SESSION['message'] === "activated") { 
     // foo
 }
?>
```

Having said that. Your problem most likley is in the function `ShowAlert()`. Do you mind sharing some details?

Comment: Problem definitely not in function, because in page code doesn't appears html that should be printed by echo. If remove function, it doesn't work too.